# how to remove a jquery balloon plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, popup-balloons

I am adding a balloon (http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js-Demo.html) object to an input filed under certain conditions but I cannot find a way to remove it dynamically (different conditions).

```
$(this).balloon({
   classname:"validationErrorBalloon",
   position:"top",
   contents: "wrong value"
});
```

Comment: strange but this plugin doesn't implement any destroy method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balloon just attaches event handlers to it to do the functionality, it might be easier to just call `off` to remove it. 
The API doesn't seem to provide a clear way.

```
$(selector).off();
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

Need not to remove manually

Give hide duration

```
$('.sample').balloon({
  showDuration: 1000, hideDuration: 500
});



$('.sample').balloon({
  hideDuration: "slow",
});
```